# Relationship between Keldysh formalism and time-dependent perturbation theory

Tags: perturbation-theory, greens-functions, non-equilibrium

When treating systems in weak external time-dependent electromagnetic field we can use usual time-dependent perturbation theory or the Keldysh formalism which is tailored for such non-equilibrium problems.

My question is, what is the relationship between them? To be more specific, I believe they are applicable to different physical situations. But I think in some parameter regime, they should give you the same result. Can anyone give more clues about the relationship between these two approaches?